# limiting number of listeners that can be created

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

My application sends bunch of notifications and for each notification,I receive a future and I attach a listener to it

The problem is that eventually the jvm will run out of memory since it sends those events and creates those listeners at a much faster rate.
I would like to block when it reaches a configurable max number of listeners allowed in my application.

What would the best way to handle this in Java?

**Note**: I used bounded blocking queue approach, where I collect all futures and process them one by one.

Is there a way to do it using listeners?

**Edit**: 
Below is the code. How do i implement backpressure here when i add listener. I would like to block if it has reached my max configured size

```
final Future<PushNotificationResponse<SimpleApnsPushNotification>> future =apnsClient.sendNotification(pushNotification);

future.addListener(new GenericFutureListener<Future<PushNotificationResponse<SimpleApnsPushNotification>>>() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(final Future<PushNotificationResponse<SimpleApnsPushNotification>> future) throws Exception {
                //do something
            }
        });
```

Comment: Umm... don't send so many notifications at once?  The question is unclear, please show some code with a better explanation of what your code is doing.  If you need to send those notifications, do you have enough memory allocated?  We need a lot more context to even consider what your question means.

Comment: Duh! use a fixedthreadpool with completionservice.

Comment: I would like to send as many notifications as possible. **sendNotification** is an async operation. Right now the application will leak memory because of so many futures that will get created.